# Best Practices for Entity Framework and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've been driving myself crazy trying to get the Entity Framework to work as expected (or at least as I expect) in an ASP.NET environment, specifically dealing with objects belonging to different contexts when attempting to save to the database.

What are the best practices when dealing with the Entity Framework and ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistence Ignorance (POCO) Adapter for Entity Framework V1
http://blogs.gotdotnet.com/jkowalski/archive/2008/09/09/persistence-ignorance-poco-adapter-for-entity-framework-v1.aspx